# ListView where all the images have the same size

Tags: android, image, listview, imageview

How can I make these pictures stay the same size?

I tried `scaleType` and `ajustbounds` but neither one works.

Look at image below

[image: Images with diferent sizes]

Custom ListView

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

Listview

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListFoto1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView14" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListFoto2"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ListFoto1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/determinate"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ListFoto1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListFoto1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListFoto3"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ListFoto2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/determinate"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ListFoto2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListFoto2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do that using custom list CustomList.java class and a single layout list_single.xml. Try this.

MainActivity.java file look like this.

```
CustomList cl; //Create cl as global variable
String[] imagename={"image1","image2"}; //create image name array or do that dynamically
Integer[] imageId={"R.drawable.image1","R.drawable.image2"};  //create image locations array or do that dynamically
ListView list; 

//inside oncreate method
list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Listview1);
cl = new CustomList(getActivity(), imagename, imageId); //initialize cl
list.setAdapter(cl);
```

CustomList.java file look like this

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] imagename;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] imagename, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.imagename = imagename;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(imagename[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

list_single.xml layout file look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

or you can set initial width and hight in imageview

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve this is by controlling the aspect ratio through a custom view. Something like this

```
/**
 * Created by victoraldir on 11/05/2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class DynamicImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    private static final float ASPECT_RATIO = 1.5f;

    public DynamicImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DynamicImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DynamicImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = Math.round(width * ASPECT_RATIO);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Then you use your custom ImageView in your XML

```
<com.my.package.DynamicImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_image"
                tools:layout_width="200dp" />
```